# How can you display either a video or image file in a Django Template depending on what type the uploaded file is?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am trying to display a file from a foreign key set of a model instance. The file can either be videos or pictures and is uploaded by users (think similar to Instagram). How can I display the file as `<video>` or `<img>` properly depending on the file type that was uploaded?

I am currently using `<video>` or `<img>` tags in html to show the file and they both work but only if the file is of the appropriate type. If the file is of the other type the incorrect tag will show a black box on the site.

```
{% if result.resultfile_set.all %}
    {% for resultfile in result.resultfile_set.all %}
        <video controls>
            <source src="{{ resultfile.file.url }}">
        </video>
        <img src="{{ resultfile.file.url }}" />
        <p>Caption: {{ resultfile.caption }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Expected results are that if the file that has been uploaded by the user is a video file, display it as such; or if the file is an image file, display it as image. Instead I am currently only able to display both file types every time where one of them displays properly and the other displays as a black box

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking the mime type ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html).

Supposed you have a model called Media:

```
class Media(models.Model):
    media = models.BinaryField(...)

    def generate_html(self):
        if mime_type(self.media) == "image":
            return <img></img>
        elif mime_type(self.media) == "video":
            return <video></video>
        else: 
            raise Exception("media type not understood")
```

Now you can use the generate_html method in your template

Answer (score 0):

You can send type of media along with url and use conditional rendering to display appropriate media

```
{% if result.resultfile_set.all %}
    {% for resultfile in result.resultfile_set.all %}
        {% if resultfile.file.type == "video" %}
            <video controls> <source src="{{ resultfile.file.url }}"> </video>
        {% elif resultfile.file.type == "image"}
            <img src="{{ resultfile.file.url }}" />
        {% else %}
            <div> Unsupported Media Format </div>
        {% endif %}
        <p>Caption: {{ resultfile.caption }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Your result.resultfile_set.all will look something like

```
[{
    file: {
        type: "image",
        url: "example.com/foo.png"
    },
    caption : "foo"
}, 
{
    file: {
        type: "video",
        url: "example.com/bar.mp4"
    },
    caption : "bar"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, How can you display either a video or image file in a Django Template, I have answer for that

Use below code

```
{% for msg in post_user %}
{% if msg.p_image_path.url|slice:"-4:" == ".mp4" %} 

#use video tag 
{% else %} 

#use image tag
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of methods finally the best solution is this:

models:

```
from mimetypes import guess_type

class Post(models.Model):
    media = models.FileField()

    def media_type_html(self):
    """
    guess_type returns a tuple like (type, encoding) and we want to access
    the type of media file in first index of tuple
    """
    type_tuple = guess_type(self.media.url, strict=True)
    if (type_tuple[0]).__contains__("image"):
        return "image"
    elif (type_tuple[0]).__contains__("video"):
        return "video"
```

in templates you can access the type like this:

```
 {% if post.media_type_html == "image" %}
    <img src="{{ post.media.url }}">
 {% elif post.media_type_html == "video" %}
    <video controls>
       <source src="{{ post.media.url }}">
    </video>
 {% endif %}
```